# What's an elegant way, in regular expressions, to deal with fencepost problems in delimited lists?

Tags: regex

Let's say I wanted to validate a string to make sure it was an indefinitely long list of single decimal digit integers, each separated by a comma and allowing for zero or more spaces.

I want to use a regular expression to make sure it is valid. I would use something like this:

```
^\d(?:\s*,\s*\d)*$
```

This string value will match:

```
"4,0 , 9  ,3, 6"
```

This string value will not match:

```
"4,0 , 9  ,3, 6,"
```

Indeed, this is the desired behavior. But is there a more elegant way to do this than to repeat the \d in the regular expression? (Imagine that \d is standing in for a much more complex real-life regular expression.)

I want to preempt certain suggestions. I'm well aware that I could do these sorts of things:

- Use a split function, trim spaces, and validate each element
  against:

  ```
  ^\d$
  ```
- Add a comma to the end of the string and validate against:

  ```
  ^(?:\d\s*,\s*)+$
  ```
- Strip out commas and spaces and validate against:

  ```
  ^\d+$
  ```

I'm simply curious if there's a shorthand or more elegant way to code the regular expression to say, "...and handle the fencepost problem."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match either the beginning of the string or the seperator like so

```
(?!,)((^|\s*,\s*)\d)+$
```

or with non-capturing groups...

```
(?!,)(?:(?:^|\s*,\s*)\d)+$
```

The negative lookahead is to make sure that the first character is not a `,`.

It gets rid of the second `\d`. Is it more elegant though? I guess that's up to you. I don't think it is in this very situation because of the simplicity of `\d`, but if you have a really complex expression instead of `\d` it can clean up the regex quite a bit.

Another way to avoid having `\d` twice would be to do something like this (I'm using C# in my example):

```
string complexExpression = @"\d"; // Whatever your actual expression is
string regex = string.Format(@"^{0}(?:\s*,\s*{0})*$", complexExpression);
```

This is completely artificial and the resulting expression is of course the same, but one could argue that it's more readable/elegant like this rather than the 100% regex solution.

Comment: @trw I edited my answer. Does your regex engine support negative lookaheads?

Comment: Yes, it does. I see that, because the engine is eager, a leading comma will still match `^|\s*,\s*`. Thanks for the negative lookahead!